# How put a Image component from next/image in position: absolue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components, nextjs-image

Can I put an element Image from 'next/image' in `{ position: absolute; left: 50% }`?
It seems that it is not affected.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`

const Test = styled(Image)`
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
`

const Page: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Test src{someImg.webp} width={500} height={500} objectFit="none" />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: check how you've given the src. its not valid syntax

Comment: it's true, i only make this code to try show how i trying make it... pls ignore the (someImg.webp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put your image in another parent div with position u like.
in your case:

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`
 const ImageContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
`


const Page: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
     <ImageContainer>
        <Image src{someImg.webp} width={500} height={500} objectFit="none"/>
     </ImageContainer>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: Tks my friend! you save my day